# Is there a spyOn analogue in QUnit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, qunit, spy

I'm writing specs for different test cases for Jasmine and QUnit to compare them and they looked the same before I needed to write a test to check if an event is binded to an element.

Event binding looks like

```
$('.page').live('click', function() { page_clicked( $(this) ) });
```

`page_clicked` is a private method but it calls for a public method of another module.

Here is a Jasmine spec:

```
it('should bind events to pages', function() {
    spyOn( search, 'get_results' );

    $('.page:eq(0)').trigger('click');

    expect( search.get_results ).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

This test works. Now I'm trying to write the same test for QUnit and can't find anything similar to spyOn. How to write this test for QUnit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Its cause QUnit doesn't have spies or mocks. But you can use the [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/) mocking framework. Your test should look like this using [sinon spy](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#spies):

```
var spy = sinon.spy(search, 'get_results');
sinon.assert.calledOnce(spy);
```

Comment: Tried to copy/paste your code but `assert(spy.calledOnce)` throws `assert is not defined` and `sinon.assert.called( spy )` throws `expected get_results to have been called at least once but was never called`

Comment: Ok it was copy/pasted from sinon doku, I fixed it.

Comment: Still doesn't work. `expected get_results to be called once but was called 0 times`. I put an alert after `get_results` call in the `page_clicked` function and the alert prompts, Jasmine test passes but QUnit + SinonJS doesn't.

Comment: Oh, it works, I just inserted `trigger('click')` in the wrong place. Thanks.